# XSLT 2.0 set a variable with for-each loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I like to create a variable which contains the full PACKAGE name path for corresponding element. (just to be able to compare paths later)

Now I have XSLT structure:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
   <xsl:if test="local-name()='PACKAGE'">
      <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="NAME/."/>
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This above structure results me the correct path, but when I try to put that output to the variable (by placing the `<xsl:variable name="myPath">` and `</xsl:variable>` outside the foreach) variable stays empty.

So why in:

```
<xsl:variable name="myPath">
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
    <xsl:if test="local-name()='PACKAGE'">
     <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="NAME/."/>
       <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

`$myPath` remains empty?
What I am missing here?

Comment: Does it work if you try and assign a numeric in the loop?

Comment: Numeric assignment won't change the situation. I'm using Oxygen with Saxon-B 9.1.0.6. It seems like the foreach loop is not accessed at all if it's placed inside the variable assigment. Script above outputs me the correct kind of path, but I'm not able to set it as a variable.

Comment: Make sure you use that variable somewhere later in your code as otherwise the XSLT processor is free to not execute the code at all. So without seeing more information I assume that Saxon is simply not executing the value of the variable as you don't use it. If you still have problems then consider to post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, that was a case. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Janne, I have posted the suggestion as answer so that you can accept it and then your question will be listed as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you use that variable somewhere later in your code as otherwise the XSLT processor is free to not execute the code at all. So without seeing more information I assume that Saxon is simply not executing the value of the variable as you don't use it.